# Simulation-Nodes (?): Add values to named attribute over time

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

As seen in the attached image, a sphere "writes" its distance to a named attribute ("Proximity") of the plane - visualised via a shader-setup.

How can I incrementally add values to this named attribute over time when the sphere moves over the plane (so I get a per-vertex-"trail", comparable to the dynamic paint)?

Maybe with simulation-nodes where it adds every frame the current values to those written during the prior frames in the named attribute?

Thanks in advance (-:

[image]

EDIT: when a location is "touched" multiple times the intensity (value) should increase in contrast to locations which are detected less - see image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

[image]

i am assuming that you want to save the minimum distance, and don't really want to add values, is that right?

Else change maximum to add.

[image]

result

[image]

if you add this, you can create a "vanishing" trail:

[image]

result:

[image]

maybe this is interesting as well for you: https://youtu.be/Z_tN_q4DTVY?si=t3tNQedQwuOOduos

Comment: Chris, that's (nearly) the result what I was looking for - just one point: I have expected that when the target gets detected more often by a vertex (e.g. when the path overlaps) the intensity increases i contrast to a location which is touched less; see attached image in first post... Maybe you have also here an answer?